# Laravel Query Builder - Get Current Time From MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, query-builder

I want to get current time of MySQL in Laravel 5.1

What I have done is

```
    $time = DB::select( DB::raw('SELECT NOW() AS end_time'));
    return $time[0]['end_time'];
```

I am getting this-

[image]

I want to get a output like it-

```
2015-10-06 17:02:32
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: "Not working" is too general. What result or error message do you get?

Comment: You are trying to access an object as an array, you will need to do something like: `$time[0]->end_time;`

Comment: Why are you querying your database for the current time? What’s wrong with `time()` in PHP?

Comment: @MartinBean sometimes the machine you are running php on is a different time than the database connection, for ETL queries, time is VERY important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the relevant [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database):

> The select method will always return an array of results. Each result
>   within the array will be a PHP StdClass object, allowing you to access
>   the values of the results.

The error you are getting is because you are trying to access the first (and only) result as an array, when it's a StdClass object. So, just try:

```
$results = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT NOW() AS end_time'));
return $results[0]->end_time;
```